# Django is only applying the first style from my css file

Tags: css, django, django-templates

For some reason django is applying only the first style from my stylesheet to my template when I runserver. For instance, i wrote three styles:

```css
#header {
    text-align: center;
};

.header-element {
    color: yellow;
};

#foo {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

in this case the style assigned to #header is being applied, but the other two are not.

I assume i have referenced my /static/ folder correctly, since the first style is being applied and "base.css" is also showing in the "network" tab on chrome.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
    <title>DataClub</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1 class="header-element">DataClub</h1>
        <h3 id="foo" class="header-element">data driven aplications</h3>
        <hr>
    </div>
    {% block body %}

    {% endblock body %}

</body>
</html>
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are adding `;` after  each definition and they are not being parsed except for the first one

```
#header {
    text-align: center;
};  <--remove ";"

.header-element {
    color: yellow;
}; <--remove ";"

#foo {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

You can check the CSS validation here [CSS Validation](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)